# How to execute PUT REST client code using playframework in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, play-ws

I am new to Scala and struggling to get a simple PUT REST client working.

I am modifying existing code which is using StandaloneAhcWSClient
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0-M2/api/java/play/libs/ws/StandaloneWSRequest.html

Version used: **play-ws**:2.8.0,  **play-ahc-ws-standalone**:2.1.2

```
  def runUrl(url: String, header: Option[(String, String)] = None, timeOut: Duration = FiniteDuration(1, SECONDS))(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[Boolean] = {
    val baseRequest = wsClient.url(url).withRequestTimeout(timeOut)
    val updatedRequest = header.fold(baseRequest){r => baseRequest.withHttpHeaders((r._1, r._2))}
    updatedRequest.put("Dummy String").map{ response =>
      logger.info(s"Why code is not reaching here ???")
      logger.info(s"url: $url got response $response")
    }
  }
```

While googling out i found POST example which looks similar to my change
https://github.com/playframework/play-ws

```
def postExampleString(ws: play.api.libs.ws.StandaloneWSClient)(
  implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
  val stringData = "Hello world"
  ws.url("...").post(stringData).map { response => /* do something */ }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling `runUrl`? Could it be that you're terminating the app before receiving the HTTP response? Did you try adding a `.recover { ... }` just to be sure as well?